# How to restrict buffer extent within land area only?

Tags: postgis, buffer, area, software-recommendations

I need to create buffer for a point feature, but the buffer area will be restricted within the land area only.

For example consider the following:
A buffer of say 500 km radius is to be generated around Washington or Rome. However the generated buffer will be covering the land area of US(west-ward) or Europe(towards east or north) only, respectively and not the water areas.

How can I achieve this, preferably in PostGIS. The input tables will be land area boundary polygons and a point layer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't in one step. It's a two step procedure. BUT you can simulate the behaviour by creating your buffer as a subquerry. Afterwards you 'select' the buffer area that intersects with your land polygon  eg:

```
WITH buffer AS 
       (select st_buffer(point.geom,500000) as geom from data.point_table) 

SELECT ST_Intersection(buffer.geom,land.geom) from buffer, data.land_table;
```

Make sure your Spatial Indexed are populated, otherwise it might take a LONG time to complete (depending on your complexity of your data)

To populate the Spatial Indexes just run `VACUUM ANALYZE [tablename];`

If you haven't create a spatial index you can create one like this:

```
CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename] USING GIST ( [geometrycolumn] );
```

Comment: I did not get your point. If I am not wrong, you said first I need to create the buffer and then intersect it with the land polygon. I do not have any problem, it being a multi step job. But the process you said will decrease the buffer area, deleting areas in the ocean. But I need the actual area, eg. the final buffer generated will have area equals to pi*r*r, r being the buffer radius. Please correct me if I am wrong.